# Angular CLI doesn't return any values from array

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have component in which i have defined array of strings

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-list',
  templateUrl: './products-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductsListComponent {
  products = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

Then i use it in html file *(products-list.component.html)* like so:

```
<p>products-list works!</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let product in products'>
    {{product}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

my question is, why does Angular doesn't show any of strings in array as list items? it just prints out paragraph tag *"products-list works!"*.I apologize for stupid question but I am just learning Angular.

Comment: Should be `<li *ngFor='let product of products'>`, `of` not `in`.

Comment: right, thanks i guess i did a typo

Comment: next time you can also use the developer tools from your browser for debugging. There you see an specific error. `Can't bind to 'ngForIn...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, use "of" instead of "in".

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products">
    {{product}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>products-list works!</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product for 
        products"> {{product}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This will output html that looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>test1 </li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```

NgFor is a built-in template directive that makes it easy to iterate over something like an array or an object and create a template for each item.

- let user creates a local variable that will be available in the template.
- of users means that we’ll be iterating over the users iterable that should be made available in our component.
- The * character before ngFor creates a parent template. It’s a shortcut to the following syntax: template=“ngFor let item of items”